# Vue 3 Composition API - Best approach for rebuild section

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a file called CreateSales.vue which is imported within Layout.vue. Important to know that this file loads the following:
`<FormModal v-if="processingData" :processingData="processingData" @gateway="saveForm" />`

When the data has come back from FormModal, a function is called that stores it via the API. This is all going fine.

The question: After the API has added things, I want to make sure that the table in the background refreshes again automatically. However, within CreateSales.vue there is no direct link (as parent/child) to SalesTable.vue (where the table is generated). So I have to consult a function within SalesTable to get the table again. What is the best working method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple ways to solve it.

- Global store
- Provide/inject
- Events api
- Add props and listeners to each component in between

### Global store

The most popular solution, I would guess, is to use a global store to handle this,  whether in the form of Vuex or a custom paired down store

Here is what the custom store might look like

*mystore.js*

```js
const {ref} from "vue";
export const STATES = {INIT:'INIT', LOADING:'LOADING', LOADED:'LOADED'};
export const loadState = ref(STATES.INIT);
```

now you can use the `mystore.js` in the two separate components

watch for  changes

```js
import {loadState, STATES} from "mystore.js";
//...
watch{
  loadState(value){
    if(value === STATES.LOADED) {
      // do something when state changed to loaded
    }
  }
}
```

and make the change

```js
import {loadState, STATES} from "mystore.js";
// ... somewhere where the API is being processed
loadState.value = STATES.LOADING;
api
  .get(url)
  .then(result => {
    // ...
    loadState.value = STATES.LOADED;
  })
```

You can also use `Vuex` which can add a bit more in terms of complexity and boilerplate, but helps with bigger applications when you have a larger store you need to manage.

### Provide/inject

Similar to the custom store, but instead of having the variables in a separate file, so as to make it globally available, you can define the `ref` in the parent component add it to `provide` then use `inject` at the descendant(s) to access the reactive variable there.

[provide-inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#provide-inject)

### Events API

the EventBus has been removed in v3 but you can still use a 3rd party event emitter like `mitt`

https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#_2-x-syntax

```js
import mitt from 'mitt';
const app = createApp(App)
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = mitt();
```

// component 1
created(){
this.emitter.on('apiLoaded', this.doStuff())
}

// component 2
api
.get(url)
.then(result => {
// ...
this.emitter.emit('apiLoaded')
})
}

### Add props and listeners to each component in between

There's enough other choices, no need to resort to this